# Stackoverflow question on queforum

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, search

I have a few questions on stackoverlow. 1 of them is unanswered so i searched for similar things to find a solution. During my google search i found [this](http://queforum.com/programming-languages-basics/590644-java-libgdx-moving-camera-table-cell.html). It is exactly my stackoverflow question (the original one, i edited it to be up do date). I was a bit shocked and searched for others of my questions and found [this](http://queforum.com/programming-languages-basics/562722-java-using-mvc-libgdx-scene2d.html) and [this](http://queforum.com/programming-languages-basics/587585-java-libgdx-how-store-data-collision-detection.html). So i started looking for other SO questions on google to see if i am the only one on the Queforum. To some questions i could find a queforum link to some not. So my questions: Why are some SO questions on queforum.com? Thanks

**EDIT:** I have seen, that there is a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204100/some-questions-posted-here-are-copied-to-queforum-com?lq=1), but it has got no answer and has been declared as possible duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers), but i don't hink it is. The question here is "Why are they on Queforum, all posted by the same user?" and the question there is "What can i do if i don'T want to have my question there?" so it is not really a duplicate.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I edited it. Please take a look at the edit

Comment: Regarding why; its good content so the scrapers stole it to drive traffic to their site. Regarding what you should do; see duplicate

Comment: @Springrbua it is a duplicate, there's nothing you can do.  Once you put it anything on the internet, it is free for anyone to steal it.  It's not like SO said "hey, come scrap this question".

Comment: However if they followed proper attribution and put your name and a link to the original it would be all good and legal as per the licence

Comment: I know that i can't do anything against and i don't realy care. I just asked why, because i always see this page (queforum.com) and the same user, but not ALL Stackoverflow questions but some. And i don't think, that she/he coppise the questions manualy :P So i just thought that there is a reason and this forum belongs to stackexchange or something like that. I did not think that there is someone out there picking some SO questions to but them in a random forum xD thanks for your comments

Comment: Its possible an algorithm decides which to steal; for example only upvoted java questions.  Either way; they aren't a part of the network

Comment: Okay thank you verry much. Can you post it as an answer please so i mark this as solved. Thanks